# SImple Coloring Book: Error #1009: Cannot access a property or method of a null object reference

Tags: actionscript-3, error-handling

I am creating a simple flash coloring book and am not very familiar with as3 programming language.

I entered the following code,and when I attempted to press the back button in the test movie I got that error.

```
stop();

back_btn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, GoToChooseA);

function GoToChooseA(event:MouseEvent):void
{
    gotoAndStop("Choose");

}

color_scroll.mask = myMask;
var goY: Number = color_scroll.y;
stage.addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, scrollManage);

function scrollManage(Event): void {
    color_scroll.y += (goY - color_scroll.y) / 20;
}

up_btn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, scrollUP);
down_btn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, scrollDown);
function scrollUP(MouseEvent): void {
    goY += 20;
}
function scrollDown(MouseEvent): void {
    goY -= 20;
}
```

*
It seems to indicate the error is here

```
color_scroll.y += (goY - color_scroll.y) / 20;
```

But I'm really bummed because I'm not really sure how to proceed from there.

Comment: did you create a new instance for `color_scroll`

Answer (score 1):

Whenever you `gotoAndStop()` to a different keyframe, your current frame is invalidated and all its members destroyed. Listeners persist, if they are attached to an object that persists. So, right after you call `GoToChooseA()`, your `color_scroll` is destroyed, and then the listener attached to `stage` is called and tries to modify a destroyed object, there goes your 1009. The solution is either manually remove the event listeners "scrollManage", "scrollUp", "scrollDown" before you change the frame, at least "scrollManage" because it's attached to stage, or stop using frames altogether, but even then you'll have to control your event listeners.

Comment: I need the scroll so i can't get rid of scroll manage, so how do i stop using frames?

Comment: Getting rid of frames will make you refactor your entire app, it's not a simple click :D And removing listeners is a piece of code placed in a proper function. You should read more about listeners and how *and when* to remove them.

Answer (score 0):

You could add some logic to your function to check if you are in the right frame and then proceed. I am not familiar with frames so the condition would be something like `this._currentframe == 2` or `timeline.currentFrame == 2`.

```
function scrollManage(Event): void {
    if ( condition ) {
    color_scroll.y += (goY - color_scroll.y) / 20;
    }
}
```

If you are not at the right frame (in my example that is frame 2), the function does not execute any code.

This error means you are trying to modify something that is no longer existent.

Comment: I'm not really sure what to put as the condition.

Comment: I edited my answer. Try `this._currentframe == 2` or `timeline.currentFrame == 2` as the condition. Replace what's necessary for your case.

Comment: But what am I supposed to put in the place of timeline? because it says that this is an undefined property.

Comment: The name/id of your object that holds the frames. I'm sorry, but my actionscript frame knowledge is limited.